# After removing application from Apple AppStore, will restoring of in-app purchases still work?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm going to remove my paid application from AppStore and wonder if in-app purchases will still work, or if they will be removed also. Are there any legal issues in the case if they will not be available anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove your app from App Store your in-app purchases are still valid and remain in approved state. So lets say you decide to put your app back in App Store then you don't need to do anything special with in-app purchases. They will be available and working.

Any existing user who had downloaded your app previously will be able to make in-app purchases. All you are doing is not letting new users download your app.

NOTE: as long as you don't "delete" your app or in-app purchases and you just make your app not available in any store / country, you should be fine.